# Read .table file into R

Tags: r, csv, knime

I just wanted to know if there is a command where I can read a .table file (TABLE file) into R. 
read.table() is not working since this is used to read a file into table format into R. I'm looking for a method of how to either convert this .table file into a csv file or directly read it in.

As of right now the only way of how I can read this file is in a software called "KNIME".

The output is as follows: However I cannot copy any of the entries.
Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: KNIME has an extension that allows you to export data from KNIME to R. A KNIME table is a proprietary format, and to my knowledge there is no R package that will read a KNIME table. See Google for details.

Comment: Oh thanks! Do you happen to know the extension? I wanted to code something in KNIME with R, since KNIME seems really unintuitive to me. Do you know how I can import my R Code into KNIME as well?

Comment: I don't know KNIME, but if you Google "KNIME table to r data frame" there are links that tell you how to convert both ways

Answer (score 0):

To write R code in KNIME you have to:

1. Install the KNIME Interactive R Statistics Integration
2. Do a bit of configuration in KNIME and possibly R
3. Use R Snippet node

For 1&2 see [here](https://docs.knime.com/latest/r_installation_guide/index.html).